# How to escape JSON in Ansible playbook

Tags: docker, ansible, yaml, escaping

I have the following YAML Ansible playbook file which I intent do use to capture some information from my docker containers:

```yaml
---
# Syntax check:  /usr/bin/ansible-playbook --syntax-check --inventory data/config/host_inventory.yaml data/config/ansible/docker_containers.yaml
- hosts: hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Docker ps output - identify running containers
    shell: "/usr/bin/docker ps --format '{\"ID\":\"{{ .ID }}\", \"Image\": \"{{ .Image }}\", \"Names\":\"{{ .Names }}\"}'"
    register: docker_ps_output
  - name: Show content of docker_ps_output
    debug:
       msg: docker_ps_output.stdout_lines
```

But escaping is not working, Ansible gives me the middle finger when I try to run the playbook:

```sh
PLAY [hosts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Docker ps output - identify running containers] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [myhost.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: /usr/bin/docker ps --format ''{\"ID\":\"{{ .ID }}\", \"Image\": \"{{ .Image }}\", \"Names\":\"{{ .Names }}\"}''"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/docker_containers.retry

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
myhost.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

The original command I'm trying to run:

```sh
/usr/bin/docker ps --format '{"ID":"{{ .ID }}", "Image": "{{ .Image }}", "Names":"{{ .Names }}"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a block scalar. Your problem is that `{{ .ID }}` etc is processed by Ansible's Jinja templating engine when it should not. Probably the most readable way around this is:

```yaml
---
# Syntax check:  /usr/bin/ansible-playbook --syntax-check --inventory data/config/host_inventory.yaml data/config/ansible/docker_containers.yaml
- hosts: hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Docker ps output - identify running containers
    shell: !unsafe >-
      /usr/bin/docker ps --format
      '{"ID":"{{ .ID }}", "Image": "{{ .Image }}", "Names":"{{ .Names }}"}'
    register: docker_ps_output
  - name: Show content of docker_ps_output
    debug:
       msg: docker_ps_output.stdout_lines
```

`>-` starts a folded block scalar, in which you do not need to escape anything and newlines are folded into spaces. The tag `!unsafe` prevents the value to be processed with Jinja.

Comment: This is great, very clean. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid templating, you need to cover double-brackets by another double-brackets:

```
{{ thmthng }}
```

should look like:

```
{{ '{{' }} thmthng {{ '}}' }}
```

Your playbook:

```
---
- hosts: hosts
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Docker ps output - identify running containers
    shell: "docker ps -a --format '{\"ID\": \"{{ '{{' }} .ID {{ '}}' }}\", \"Image\": \"{{ '{{' }} .Image {{ '}}' }}\", \"Names\" : \"{{ '{{' }} .Names {{ '}}' }}}\"'"
    register: docker_ps_output

  - name: Show content of docker_ps_output
    debug:
       var: docker_ps_output.stdout_lines
```